# javascript matching a term that may or may not exist, but should be matching if exist

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a string `'dsda[RESP]dasd'` The [RESP] may not exist. I like to catch it if exists.
The regexp is `/.*(\[RESP\])?.*/` but always fail to catch `[RESP]`. But if I using `/.*(\[RESP\]).*/` It always catch `[RESP]`
Any way can fix it?
[image: The demo in chrome console]

Comment: If your second regex is working what's the problem?

Comment: yep works fine https://regex101.com/r/KKfz4n/1 with /.*(\[RESP\]).*/gi

Comment: @Andy and Marko I have uploaded a screenshot. You can see that not work at chrome console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(.*?)(?:(\[RESP\])(.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bgHZwy/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:(\[RESP\])(.*))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `(\[RESP\])` - Group 2: `[RESP]`
  - `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: While this might be nice, it does not explain why the ones from the OP are not working.

Comment: @Lain OP did not ask to explain their patterns, but it is clear why: 1) `/.*(\[RESP\]).*/` is wrong as `[RESP]` pattern is obligatory and strings without this substring will never match, 2) `/.*(\[RESP\])?.*/` never captures `[RESP]` because the first `.*` matches the whole string and the subsequent patterns, all being optional, simply happily match the end of string position, an empty string there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why I using this `^(.*?)(?:(\[RESP\]))?.*$` not working. That's looks the same. And there others field in the last `.*` so I can not set it into `()`

Comment: @sinbar Please watch my [*Matching a whole string and capturing any text before and after an optional word*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlwN8BJHZN0&t=2s) video that should clarify everything. If not, please let me know.